# How can I define new colors in a CPropertySheet?

Tags: c++, mfc, cpropertysheet, cmfcpropertypage

I'm trying to define new colors in some regions of a CPropertySheet (mfc libaries). What I've tried is to overload `OnCtlColor`and define a new background color. This methods works well but it doesn't colorize the region I want.

In the next image you can see what I get with my method.

[Image of the control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAayj.png)

In this image you can see 4 colorized regions:

1. Red: Region that I can colorize using `OnCtlColor`
2. Dark Gray and black: Region that I can colorize using `OnCtlColor`
   of the object CPropertyPage
3. Light Gray (Indicated with a blue arrow): Region I want to colorize
4. White margin: Region I want to colorize too.

I don't know what to do to colorize all regions using this libraries or using any Customizable object. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

### **Update 1**

After the answer of Adrian it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OovkL.png)

However, there's still one region we cannot colorize.

### **Answer**

Before trying a lot of combinations, I've done the next two objects which allows me to define the colors I need. You can find all source code behind. The result of this code can be checked in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MouA4.png) picture

**PropertyPage**

Header

```
class CustomPropertyPage : public CPropertyPage
{   
    public:
        static const COLORREF PROPERTYPAGE_BACKGROUND = RGB(68, 74, 80);
        DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

    public:
        CustomPropertyPage(UINT nIDTemplate);
        afx_msg HBRUSH OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor);
};
```

cpp

```
CustomPropertyPage::CustomPropertyPage(UINT nIDTemplate) : CPropertyPage(nIDTemplate)
{
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CustomPropertyPage, CPropertyPage)
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

HBRUSH CustomPropertyPage::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    if (pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() != 0)
        return CPropertyPage::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

    HBRUSH hbr = CreateSolidBrush(PROPERTYPAGE_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
    return hbr;
}
```

**PropertySheet**

Header

```
class CustomPropertySheet : public CPropertySheet
{
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

    public:
        CustomPropertySheet(UINT nIDCaption, CWnd* pParentWnd, UINT iSelectPage);
        virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
        afx_msg void OnDrawItem(int nIDCtl, LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct);
        afx_msg HBRUSH OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor);

    private:
        void Draw_Background(CDC *pDC);
};
```

cpp

```
CustomPropertySheet::CustomPropertySheet(UINT nIDCaption, CWnd* pParentWnd, UINT iSelectPage) : CPropertySheet(nIDCaption, pParentWnd, iSelectPage)
{
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CustomPropertySheet, CPropertySheet)
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()
    ON_WM_DRAWITEM()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CustomPropertySheet::OnInitDialog()
{
    BOOL answer = CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog();

    CWnd* pTab = GetDlgItem(AFX_IDC_TAB_CONTROL);
    SetWindowLongPtr(pTab->m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLongPtr(pTab->m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE) | TCS_OWNERDRAWFIXED);
    pTab->RedrawWindow();

    return answer;
}

void CustomPropertySheet::OnDrawItem(int nIDCtl, LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
{
    if (nIDCtl == AFX_IDC_TAB_CONTROL)
    {
        CDC* pDC = CDC::FromHandle(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);
        Draw_Background(pDC);

        CRect rc(lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem);
        rc.bottom += 1;
        pDC->FillSolidRect(rc, CEasyPropertyPage::PROPERTYPAGE_BACKGROUND);
        pDC->SetTextColor(GENERIC_TEXT_COLOR);
        pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);

        char  text[256];
        TCITEM tci = { TCIF_TEXT | TCIF_STATE, 0, 0, text, 255, -1, 0 };
        HWND tcw = ::GetDlgItem(m_hWnd, nIDCtl);
        int i, tic = int(::SendMessage(tcw, TCM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0));
        for (i = 0; i < tic; ++i) 
        {
            if (lpDrawItemStruct->itemState & ODS_SELECTED)
            {
                CRect tir;
                ::SendMessage(tcw, TCM_GETITEM, WPARAM(i), LPARAM(&tci));
                ::SendMessage(tcw, TCM_GETITEMRECT, WPARAM(i), LPARAM(&tir));
                pDC->DrawText(text, tir, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);
            }
        }
    }

    else CPropertySheet::OnDrawItem(nIDCtl, lpDrawItemStruct);
}

HBRUSH CustomPropertySheet::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    if (pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() != 0)
        return CPropertySheet::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

    HBRUSH hbr = CreateSolidBrush(GENERIC_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
    return hbr;
}

void CustomPropertySheet::Draw_Background(CDC* pDC)
{
    CRect rect; this->GetClientRect(rect);
    pDC->FillSolidRect(rect, GENERIC_BACKGROUND_COLOR);

    rect.DeflateRect(0, 20, 0, 0);
    pDC->FillSolidRect(rect, GENERIC_BORDER_COLOR);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize the light gray area (which is the embedded **tab control**) you need to override the `OnDrawItem` method in your class that is derived from `CPropertySheet` and do your custom drawing for the control with the `AFX_IDC_TAB_CONTROL` identifier. Something like this:

```cpp
void MyPropertySheet::OnDrawItem(int nID, LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT pDIS)
{   
    if (nID == AFX_IDC_TAB_CONTROL) {
        CDC* pDC = CDC::FromHandle(pDIS->hDC);
        CRect rc(pDIS->rcItem); rc.bottom += 1;
        pDC->FillSolidRect(rc, RGB(255, 0, 0)); // Or whatever b/g/ colour you want
        pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(0,0,0)); // Or whatever text colour you want
        pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
        char  text[256];
        TCITEM tci = { TCIF_TEXT | TCIF_STATE, 0, 0, text, 255, -1, 0 };
        CRect tir;
        HWND tcw = ::GetDlgItem(m_hWnd, nID);
        int i, tic = int(::SendMessage(tcw, TCM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0));
        for (i = 0; i < tic; ++i) {
            ::SendMessage(tcw, TCM_GETITEM, WPARAM(i), LPARAM(&tci));
            ::SendMessage(tcw, TCM_GETITEMRECT, WPARAM(i), LPARAM(&tir));
            if (pDIS->itemState & ODS_SELECTED)
                pDC->DrawText(text, tir, DT_CENTER |DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);
        }
        pDC->Detach();
    }
    else { // Pass other stuff to the base class
        CPropertySheet::OnDrawItem(nID, pDIS);
    }
    return;
}
```

Of course, be sure to add `ON_WM_DRAWITEM()` to the message map!

EDIT: You must also **explicitly** set the style of the embedded tab control to include `TCS_OWNERDRAWFIXED`. You can do this in the `OnInitDialog` override for your class.

EDIT 2: I have a slightly better way to get a pointer to the tab control, now! Also, I have added a few lines of code that act as a "cheat" to address the remaining area that needs to be coloured - by expanding the tabs to fit the width of the underlying control ...

```cpp
BOOL MyPropertySheet::OnInitDialog()
{
    BOOL answer = CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog(); // Call base class first!
    // ... whatever other stuff you may wish to do
//  CWnd* pTab = GetDlgItem(AFX_IDC_TAB_CONTROL);
    CTabCtrl* pTab = GetTabControl(); // This is a bit clearer than above line!
    // The following 4 lines comprise a 'first stab' at fixing the remaining issue:
    CRect rcTab; pTab->GetWindowRect(&rcTab);
    int nItems = pTab->GetItemCount();
    int border = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE) * 2;
    pTab->SetMinTabWidth((rcTab.Width() - border) / nItems);
    // ...
    SetWindowLongPtr(pTab->m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLongPtr(pTab->m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE) | TCS_OWNERDRAWFIXED);
    pTab->RedrawWindow();
    return answer;
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Works really good! However, There's still one region I can't fill with my color. Those parts which aren't included in a tab still have light gray color (Part where the blue arrow is placed). Do you know what I have to do to fill that place too?

Comment: @pH4ngH0st Can you post an image of what it looks like after this 'first round' of treatment? The I may be able to see how we can do something (probably quote similar) for the remaining area(s).

Comment: @pH4ngH0st Actually, I'm pretty sure I know what you mean already. In the project of mine where I snatched the code I posted from, I generally have enough 'tabs' to fill the whole area! However, I found one P/Sheet where I didn't, and that also retains the original (gray) colour! Thinking hat is now on.

Comment: @pH4ngH0st See latest edit! It's not an ideal solution, I admit - but maybe will work as a placeholder. A more robust solution may require sub-classing the tab control and overriding its `OnPaint` or `OnEraseBackground` functions.

Comment: Well, after all your code into mine, I've done one object that allows me to colorize all area. This code can be found insede the question. Thanks for all your research!